# no matching function when return different template type from the original

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I wrote a simple template matrix class, the getMat function should return a sub matrix of the original with different size , so I coded like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template<size_t _m, size_t _n> 
Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd> Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>::getMat(const size_t& ulrow, const size_t& ulcol ) const 
{
    assert(_m+ulcol <= m && _n+ulrow <= n) ;
    T temp[_m*_n] ;
    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < _m ; ++j)
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _n ; ++i)
            temp[j*_n+i] = data[(ulrow + j) * n + ulcol+i] ;
    return Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd>(temp) ;
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
Matrix<double, 4,4> testmat2(100.0) ;
Matrix<double,2,2> testmat4 =  testmat2.getMat(0,0) ;
```

And it shows error like this:

```
main.cpp:127: error: no matching function for call to ‘Matrix<double, 4ul, 4ul, std::equal_to<double> >::getMat(size_t, size_t)’
```

So my question is why compiler doesn't detect this getMat function ?

**Update:**

I tried code in this way and it works:

```
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template<size_t _m, size_t _n> 
void Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>::getMat(Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd>& result, const size_t& ulrow, const size_t& ulcol) const
{
    assert(_m+ulcol <= m && _n+ulrow <= n) ;

    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < _m ; ++j)
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _n ; ++i)
            result[j*_n+i] = data[(ulrow + j) * n + ulcol+i] ;

}
```

This is to pass the sub matrix to be modified as a reference.

So my problem is that when this function return a different template type (same object), the compiler doesn't detect this function at all.

But I used this technique before on many conversion operators and they work.
For example, this one works:

```
template<typename T, int cn, typename _Prd>
template<typename U, typename _Prd2>
Vec<T,cn,_Prd>::operator Vec<U,cn,_Prd2>() const 
{
  U temp[cn] ;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < cn ; ++i)
    temp[i] = static_cast<U>(this->data[i]) ;
  Vec<U,cn,_Prd2> v(temp) ;
  return v ;
};
```

**Update2:**

I modified the code according to iammilind:

```
template<size_t _m, size_t _n> 
Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd> getMat<_m,_n>(const size_t& ulrow, const size_t& ulcol) const ;
// the declaration in the class.

template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template<size_t _m, size_t _n> 
Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd> Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>::getMat<_m,_n>(const size_t& ulrow, const size_t& ulcol ) const 
{
    assert(_m+ulcol <= m && _n+ulrow <= n) ;
    T temp[_m*_n] ;
    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < _m ; ++j)
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _n ; ++i)
            temp[j*_n+i] = data[(ulrow + j) * n + ulcol+i] ;
    return Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd>(temp) ;
}
```

And I call it as:

```
Matrix<double,2,2> testmat7 = testmat2.getMat<2,2>(0,0) ;
```

But it doesn't compile:

```
In file included from main.cpp:13:
Matrix.hpp:125: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
In file included from main.cpp:13:
Matrix.hpp:268: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:135: error: ‘class Matrix<double, 4ul, 4ul, std::equal_to<double> >’ has no member named ‘getMat’
main.cpp:135: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

Thanks.

Comment: `getMat()` is also a `template` function so you have to call it as `testmat2.getMat<_m,_n>(0,0)` where `_m`,`_n` is your choice. However your code is very confusing.

Comment: @iammilind, I think you are right. can I ask why it's confusing ?

Comment: @iammilind, I don't think template function is the problem, I modified according to your suggestion, but it doesn't compile, could you please provide more information ?

Comment: @tomriddle_1234, you can paste in your question that how are you calling `getMat<>` in your code. It still shows the old way.

Comment: @iammilind, it's there. thanks so much

Comment: Can you try `template Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd>(temp);` in your original code. Seems to be a special case problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you have this declaration

```
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template<size_t _m, size_t _n> 
Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd> Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>::getMat(const size_t& ulrow, const size_t& ulcol ) const
```

The compiler needs to deduce 6 template arguments. Four of these (i.e., `T`, `m`, `n`, and `_Prd`) can be deduced from the object you call the function. The other two, i.e., `_m` and `_n`) cannot be deduced. You could explicit specify them, though:

```
Matrix<double, 4,4> testmat2(100.0);
Matrix<double,2,2> testmat4 = testmat2.getMat<2, 2>(0,0);
```

If `testmat2` ends up being a dependent name, you need to slip in an extra `template` keyword:

```
template <int Size>
void f() {
    Matrix<double, 4, Size> testmat2(100.0);
    Matrix<double, 2, 2>    testmat4 = testmat2.template getMat<2, 2>(0,0);
}
```

The compiler won't use the type the result is assigned to to deduce the template arguments (the type is sometimes used but only if there is a ready overload set and it needs to choose the address of a function pointer or a member function pointer out of these, I think).

The conversion operator can deduce the additional arguments because it doesn't really have a return type but gets another argument from which it can potentially deduce template arguments. The errors you get for your later updates are probably due to the way you declare the function:

```
template<size_t _m, size_t _n> 
Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd> getMat<_m,_n>(const size_t& ulrow, const size_t& ulcol) const ;
```

The `<_m, _n>` after `getMat()` don't go there.

Comment: Thanks so much for this clearer answer, however, I still don't know how would I program a reasonable getMat function for my template class without using ridiculous extra template syntax? What's the proper way of coding a getMat allowing to use like this  Matrix<double,2,2> testmat4 = testmat2.getMat(0,0) ; ? Should I make this function outside the class ? Or should I code a sub matrix constructor instead of the getMat function ?

Comment: I would just make it a constructor: `Matrix<double, 2, 2> testmat4(testmat2);` and a similar approach for assignment (however, the `T a = v;` notation isn't assignment, i.e., this wouldn't be supported). There is no way to deduce in the return type of `getMat()` what is happening next to the object. You could potentially create some sort of handle which keeps a pointer to the original and just has a conversion operator but I'd got withe constructor and assignment.