# Declare a partial specified templated matrix multiplication operator overload function as friend outside the class

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I'm writing a matrix base class, and met the problem as the title.

Here is my declaration.

```
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template <size_t _m, size_t _n>
const Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> operator* (const Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>& lhs, const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd>& rhs) ; // matrix mult
```

And friend declaration inside class.

```
template <size_t _m, size_t _n>
friend const Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> operator* <>(const Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>& lhs, const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd>& rhs) ;
```

And implementation:

```
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template <size_t _m, size_t _n>
const Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> operator* (const Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>& lhs, const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd>& rhs) 
{
    assert (n == _m) ;
    Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> result ;

    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < m ; ++j)
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _n ; ++ i)

            for (size_t k = 0 ; k < n ; ++ k) 
                result.at(j,i) += lhs.at(j,k) * rhs.at(k,i) ;

    return result ;
}
```

However these don't compile, the error is:

```
In file included from main.cpp:13:
Matrix.hpp:43: error: too many template-parameter-lists
Matrix.hpp:66: error: invalid use of template-id ‘operator*<>’ in declaration of primary template
In file included from main.cpp:13:
Matrix.hpp:364: error: too many template-parameter-lists
```

I met another problem on the same class here [no matching function when return different template type from the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505920/no-matching-function-when-return-different-template-type-from-the-original)

**Update** :

I modified according to the suggestions under, however it still doesn't work.

Forward declaration :

```
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd,size_t _m, size_t _n>
const Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> operator* (const Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>& lhs, const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd>& rhs) ; // matrix mult
```

Friend declaration inside class:

```
template <size_t _m, size_t _n>
friend const Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> operator* (const Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>& lhs, const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd>& rhs) ;
```

Implementation :

```
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd,size_t _m, size_t _n>

const Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> operator* (const Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>& lhs, const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd>& rhs) 
{
    assert (n == _m) ;
    Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> result ;

    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < m ; ++j)
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _n ; ++ i)

            for (size_t k = 0 ; k < n ; ++ k) 
                result.at(j,i) += lhs.at(j,k) * rhs.at(k,i) ;

    return result ;
}
```

But when I want to use it like this:

```
Matrix<double,2,3> testmat8(10.0) ;
Matrix<double,3,4> testmat9(2.0) ;
Matrix<double,2,4> testmat10 ;
testmat10 = testmat8 * testmat9 ;
```

Error is:

```
main.cpp:143: undefined reference to `Matrix<double, 2ul, 4ul, std::equal_to<double> > const operator*<3ul, 4ul>(Matrix<double, 2ul, 3ul, std::equal_to<double> > const&, Matrix<double, 3ul, 4ul, std::equal_to<double> > const&)'
```

Still unsolved...

**Update2:**

To clarify my purpose I coded 3 work around. However not all of them work as expected.

```
//member operator * rather than friend function
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template<size_t _m, size_t _n>
Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>::operator *(const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd> & rhs) const 
{
    assert (n == _m) ;
    Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> result ;
    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < m ; ++j)
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _n ; ++ i)
            for (size_t k = 0 ; k < n ; ++ k) 
                result.at(j,i) += this->at(j,k) * rhs.at(k,i) ;
    return result ;
}


//work around for *
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template<size_t _m, size_t _n>
void Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>::mul (Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> & result, const Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd> & A, const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd> & B) 
{
    assert (n == _m) ;
    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < m ; ++j)
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _n ; ++ i)

            for (size_t k = 0 ; k < n ; ++ k) 
                result.at(j,i) += A.at(j,k) * B.at(k,i) ;
}

template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template<size_t _m, size_t _n>
Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>::mul(const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd> & B) const 
{
    assert (n == _m) ;
    Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> result ;

    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < m ; ++j)
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _n ; ++ i)

            for (size_t k = 0 ; k < n ; ++ k) 
                result.at(j,i) += this->at(j,k) * B.at(k,i) ;

    return result ;
}
```

And I call them in this way:

```
    testmat10 = testmat8 * testmat9 ; //works, but I have to comment out the friend operator * overload outside of the class.
    testmat10 = testmat8.mul(testmat9) ; //works, but mul() has to be a member, not as expected as a friend .
    Matrix<double,2,3>::mul(testmat10, testmat8, testmat9) ; 
//works, but this is ridiculous, for a static function, how would I avoid use <double,2,3> as the testmat8's template before using mul? I shouldn't have used template when I use mul in this way.
```

But what the answer I want is someone could clarify why the non-member operator * could not do the same as the first mul() ? And what is the proper way of coding my matrix multiplication function ?

**Update3: (Solved)**
Thanks to jpalecek, I modified my code according to his answer.

Forward declaration:

```
template < typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd, size_t _m, size_t _n> 
const Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> operator * (const Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>& lhs, const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd> & rhs) ;
```

Friend declaration:

```
// here is tricky
template <typename U, size_t mm, size_t nn, typename _Prd2, size_t _m, size_t _n>
friend const Matrix<U,mm,_n,_Prd2> operator* (const Matrix<U,mm,nn,_Prd2>& lhs, const Matrix<U,_m,_n,_Prd2>& rhs) ;
```

Implementation:

```
template <typename U, size_t mm, size_t nn, typename _Prd2, size_t _m, size_t _n>
const Matrix<U,mm,_n,_Prd2> operator* (const Matrix<U,mm,nn,_Prd2>& lhs, const Matrix<U,_m,_n,_Prd2>& rhs) 
{
    return lhs.mul(rhs) ;
}
```

mul() as member function:

```
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template<size_t _m, size_t _n>
Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> Matrix<T,m,n,_Prd>::mul(const Matrix<T,_m,_n,_Prd> & B) const 
{
    assert (n == _m) ;
    Matrix<T,m,_n,_Prd> result ;
    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < m ; ++j)
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < _n ; ++ i)
            for (size_t k = 0 ; k < n ; ++ k) 
                result.at(j,i) += this->at(j,k) * B.at(k,i) ;
    return result ;
}
```

Usage:

```
//test * operator, all work
Matrix<double,2,3> testmat8(10.0) ;
Matrix<double,3,4> testmat9(2.0) ;
Matrix<double,4,4> testmat11(3.0) ;
Matrix<double,2,4> testmat10 ;
testmat10 = testmat8 * testmat9 * testmat11;
cout <<testmat10<<endl ;
testmat10 = testmat8.mul(testmat9) ;
cout << testmat10 << endl ;
```

Comment: Lose the `template <size_t _m, size_t _n>` in your declarations, for starters.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks, but I didn't get your answer. what did you mean exactly ?

Comment: See icepacks answer. Your syntax is not correct.

Comment: @WhozCraig, would you kindly show me how to correct it ? I still don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you cannot befriend a partial specialization of a function (these do not exist) or a family of specializations. So it's either all specializations of a function, or a single one:

```
template <class T> class A;
template <class T, class U>
void operator*(A<T>, A<U>);

template <class T>
class A {
    template <class X, class U>
    friend void ::operator*(A<X>, A<U>);
```

would be for all specializations (you would have to replace the parameter list with your 6 arguments),

```
  friend void ::operator*<>(A<T>, A<T>);
```

would mean the one specific specialization (that's not what you want). Examples [here](http://ideone.com/shVcRP) and [here](http://ideone.com/eDUOIs).

Comment: I'm so appreciated, jpalecek, exactly as you said. This is so tricky.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is invalid. You're parametrizing the template twice:

```
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n, typename _Prd>
template <size_t _m, size_t _n>
```

This has no defined meaning. `template<...>` should be followed by the body/declaration of your `operator*`, not by another `template<...>`.

Also see here: ["too many template-parameter-lists" error when specializing a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595859/too-many-template-parameter-lists-error-when-specializing-a-member-function)

Comment: Could you please paste modified code here, I didn't quite get your answer, I have been using double template declaration before which was fine.

Comment: You should probably unite both lists into one. See the attached link.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, however my problem is different from the attached link, they just need a void function, my mine returns a different templated type. I modified my code according to your suggestion, it compiles though, but it doesn't work when I actually use is like Matrix<double,2,4> test = (Matrix<double,2,3>) A * (Matrix<double,3,4>) B ;